# Получить значение value до отправки формы

Tags: php

При переходе на страницу есть скрытое поле ввода, в котором уже есть какое-то значение. Вопрос - как его получить до отправки формы? может быть как-то регулярными выражениями?

вот этот поле:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf-backend" value="тут-текст">
```

мне нужно только **тут-текст**

Буду благодарен за помощь.

P.S. нужно только средствами php, учитывая то что это поле ввода вставлено в разметку страницы, то есть не одна строка с этим полем, а целая страница, где есть и другие поля...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно рассмотреть такой вариант:

```
$string = '<input type="hidden" name="_csrf-backend" value="тут-текст">';

preg_match_all('~"_csrf-backend"\svalue="(.*?)">~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => тут-текст
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понимаю почему нельзя выявить значение на клиенте через js?

Если вдруг пригодится, то код ниже: 
**js** `document.querySelector("input[name='_csrf-backend']").value` 
**JQuery** `$("input[name='_csrf-backend']").val();`